# Reading from a TcpStream with Read::read_to_string hangs until the connection is closed by the remote end

Tags: io, rust, network-programming

I'm attempting to implement the [Haskell IRC bot tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot) in Rust and am having some difficulty reading what the server sends me after connecting. What seems to happen is that I connect, read ~5 KB from the server, and then roughly 240 seconds later everything is dumped at once instead of being read line-by-line. The connection is closed by a ping timeout, which should happen eventually, since I don't yet have a ping-pong function to reply with.

Here's what I have so far:

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("irc.freenode.org:6667").unwrap();

    let _ = stream.write(b"NICK G-SERUFU\r\n");
    let _ = stream.write(b"USER G-SERUFU 0 * :brobot\r\n");
    let _ = stream.write(b"JOIN #tutbot-testing\r\n");

    let mut line = String::with_capacity(512);
    loop {
        let result = stream.read_to_string(&mut line);
        match result {
            Ok(n) => println!("Received {} bytes", n),
            _ => {}
        }
        line.clear();
    }
}
```

When I modify the loop a to use an array instead of a string, I immediately get the output I expect:

```
let mut line;
loop {
    line = [0; 512];
    let result = stream.read(&mut line);
    match result {
        Ok(n) => println!("Received {} bytes",n),
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

My conclusion is that `stream.read_to_string(&mut line)` is somehow the culprit. Why might that be the case? Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking?

To be more specific, in the first case the output appears after the ping timeout, upon which the following is printed:

```
//Around 4 minutes elapse before anything is printed to console
Received 5323 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
//Continues to print "Received 0 bytes" since the connection has closed but I haven't broken out of the infinite loop
```

In the second case using the array, I receive the correct output almost immediately:

```
Received 64 bytes
Received 51 bytes
Received 512 bytes
Received 512 bytes
Received 350 bytes
Received 512 bytes
Received 512 bytes
...
```

Comment: please describe exactly what happens in both cases. the problem can be related to how `stream.read` overloads differs for string and array, e.g. in case of string it can wait for 512 bytes received before returning while for array it returns immediately even if received less. most probably it's not true (would be weird logic) but you got the idea

Comment: @AndriyTylychko It might be weird, but that is definitively the case. It seems the "overloading" difference between array or arbitrary -> array with defined length, then return xx bytes. string with undefined length -> wait for EOF.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the [docs for `Read::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string), emphasis mine:

> Read all bytes **until EOF** in this source, placing them into `buf`.

Likewise for [`Read::read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end):

> Read all bytes **until EOF** in this source, placing them into `buf`.

Notably, you aren't reading *512* bytes in the first example, you are pre-allocating 512 bytes of space and then reading *every* byte until the socket closes - 4 minutes later.

It sounds like you want to use [`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> Read all bytes until a newline byte (the 0xA byte) is reached, and append them to the provided buffer.
>
> This function will continue to read (and buffer) bytes from the underlying stream until the newline delimiter (the 0xA byte) or EOF is found. Once found, all bytes up to, and including, the delimiter (if found) will be appended to buf.

You can also any other technique that will read a fixed amount of data before returning. One such example would be [`Read::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take), which will cap the total number of bytes you can read at a time.

Comment: The question is about `TCPStream`, on which, as far as I know, one cannot apply `BufRead::read_line`, isn't it?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Sorry I'm late, but no, you can apply it. BufReader can Buffer ANY type that implements Read, and TcpStream is no different. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html

Comment: @tomdemuyt that all depends on what data you are sending. This question sends line-delimited data, so reading a full line via `read_line` makes sense. If your data doesn't use line-delimited data, it's not a good idea to use `read_line`. That's why I mention using techniques like [`Read::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take).