# UnixStream write/read full string

Tags: rust, unix-socket

I have this small example version of a problem that I have:

```rust
#[test]
fn streams() {
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    use std::net::Shutdown;
    use std::os::unix::net::UnixStream;
    use std::time::Duration;

    let (mut s1, mut s2) = UnixStream::pair().unwrap();
    s1.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
    // Problem is that if not calling shutdown message never arrives
    s1.shutdown(Shutdown::Write).unwrap();
    let mut response = String::new();
    s2.read_to_string(&mut response).unwrap();
    assert_eq!("hello world".to_string(), response);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94fd65e3e20ec2af6e8613e6a79620f5)

I need to close the connection, otherwise, the message never arrives.
I think the issue is that `write_all` does not write EOF, so when using `read_to_string` hangs.

In python for example I would simply use:

```py
socket.sendall(message.encode())
data = socket.recv(1024)
```

to send and get a reply.

How could I achieve the same with rust?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@edwardw explanation make me realize that I should know the size of the message or close the connection. But I found another way of doing it that fitted better to what I needed, took quite interesting information from this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30553312/1695172):

```
    let (mut s1, mut s2) = UnixStream::pair().unwrap();
    s1.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
    let mut buff = [0; 1024];
    let mut h = s2.take(1024);
    h.read(&mut buff);
    let mut response = String::from_utf8(buff.to_vec()).unwrap();
    let res = response.trim_end_matches(char::from(0));
    assert_eq!("hello world".to_string(), res);
```

It may be worst for some cases, but for now it will do. Just making the stream to read up to `1024` bytes and then just trimming what I did not need from the string.

Answer (score 1):

The semantic of [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) is:

> Read all bytes until EOF in this source, appending them to buf.
>
> If successful, this function returns the number of bytes which were read and appended to buf.

So it will hang if you don't close the stream. You want to use `read` instead:

```rust
    let (mut s1, mut s2) = UnixStream::pair().unwrap();
    s1.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    let count = s2.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    let response = String::from_utf8(buf[..count].to_vec()).unwrap();
    assert_eq!("hello world".to_string(), response);
```

Comment: can i not just read `1024` bytes, even if I do not write them? Seems to work with the python snippet. Why won't here?

Comment: You can and I edit the answer to reflect that. Just that the semantic of `read_to_string` is to "Read all bytes until EOF in this source, appending them to buf.". So it'll hang if you don't close the stream.

Comment: thanks for your help, I finally decided to use `take`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647802/1695172