# TcpStream hangs after parsing \u{d}\u{a}

Tags: rust, tcpserver

I am trying to extend the example from the simple HTTP parser;

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html

And when I parse the request, the server always hangs on the line after the last head line.
I added some logging for each line, and write out the '2' character \d\a line;

```
1:20:GET /data HTTP/1.1
2:22:Host: localhost:7878
3:25:User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
4:13:Accept: */*
5:20:Content-Length: 27
6:49:Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
7:2:
\u{d}
\u{a}
```

Why does it do that, you can test this by running the code and then running
curl http://localhost:7878

You should see it hang and when you press Control C, you will see the rust log show

```
Natural end of HTTP request reached
We made it out!
```

This is the code where things go wrong;

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::net::TcpListener;

enum LogLevel {
  DEBUG=0,
  NORMAL=1,
  PROD=2
}

const LOG_LEVEL : LogLevel = LogLevel::DEBUG;

const GET:i8 = 1;
const OOPS:i8 = -1;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();
    log("Server started".to_string(), LogLevel::PROD);

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        handle_connection(stream.unwrap());
    }
}

fn validate_request_verb(verb: String)->i8 {
  if verb.eq("GET") {
    return GET;
  }
  return OOPS;
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {

    let mut line_count = 0;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream.try_clone().unwrap());
    let mut request_verb:i8 = OOPS;

    loop {
        line_count = line_count + 1;
        let mut line = String::new();
        let line_size  = reader.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
        if line_size > 0 {
            log(format!("{}:{}:{}", line_count, line_size, line), LogLevel::DEBUG);
            if line_count == 1 {
                let mut token_counter = 1;
                for token in line.split_whitespace(){
                    if token_counter == 1 {
                      request_verb = validate_request_verb(token.to_string());
                    }
                    token_counter = token_counter + 1;
                }
            } else { //line_count > 2
                if request_verb == GET && !line.contains(": ") {
                    //spell_out(line);
                    //TODO: this only works for GET
                    //break;

                }
            }
        } else { //Count == 0
            log("Natural end of HTTP request reached".into(), LogLevel::NORMAL);
            break;
        }
        if line_count > 100 {
            log("HTTP request had more than 100 lines".into(), LogLevel::NORMAL);
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("We made it out!");

    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap();

    let response = format!(
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n\r\n{}",
        contents.len(),
        contents
    );

    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}

fn log(message: String , maximum_log_level:LogLevel){
  if LOG_LEVEL as i8 <= maximum_log_level as i8 {
      if message.ends_with("\n") {
          print!("{}", message);
      } else {
          println!("{}", message);
      }
  }
}

fn spell_out(s: String){
    for c in s.chars(){
        println!("{}", c.escape_unicode());
    }
}
```

On a final note, according to

[Reading from a TcpStream with Read::read_to_string hangs until the connection is closed by the remote end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552187/reading-from-a-tcpstream-with-readread-to-string-hangs-until-the-connection-is)

this should be fixed by using `read_to_string`, but no luck..

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line). It returns the number of bytes read, which *includes* the newline itself. So it will never be `0` unless the stream is closed, and thus your `else { // Count == 0` won't be reached to break out of the loop naturally.

Comment: Will update the question fully when I am home, but when I do a post, there is more data to be processed, but it will still hang right there.. Also, I am expecting an EOF at the end of the tpcstream, is that not realistic?

Comment: The tcp connection won't close until you've sent the response, so waiting for an EOF while reading likely won't work.